# JAXWS - help required to set WSDL request timeout

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

Im using Metro 2.0 and J2SE5. The application I have written does not know about the external WebService at compile time, it finds them at runtime based on a business logic XML file, therefore I perform a WSDL request.

The sample code I have written is as follows:

`String wsdlServiceName = ...;
    String wsdlURL = ...;
    Document payload = ...;`

```
final String nsURI = ...;
final QName serviceName = new QName(nsURI, wsdlServiceName + "Service");
final QName servicePort = new QName(nsURI, wsdlServiceName + "Port");

// Create service and the dispatcher for the SOAP message
Service service = Service.create(new URL(wsdlURL), serviceName);
dispatch = service.createDispatch(servicePort, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);

// Set timeouts
dispatch.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", 3000);
dispatch.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", 3000);

// Create the outgoing SOAP request
SOAPBinding soapBinding = (SOAPBinding) dispatch.getBinding();
request = soapBinding.getMessageFactory().createMessage();

SOAPBody requestBody = request.getSOAPBody();
requestBody.addDocument(payload);

// Invoke web service operation 
SOAPMessage response = dispatch.invoke(request);
```

The timeout works correctly when the Web Service is invoked ( dispatcher.invoke(request) )

**HOWEVER the WSDL is requested before the timeouts are set, and if the Web Service is not responding it takes 90 seconds before the connection is timed-out.**

**Is it possible to set the timeouts before the WSDL is requested ? You need a dispatcher to set the timeouts, but that is done AFTER the Service is created that requests the WSDL?!   (ie. Service.create() )**

Answer (score 3):

Try the setting system property

```
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout
```

but from [Networking Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html) it says it may not be supported for in future releases

However I would suggest to cache the WSDL and not access it remotely.
It is better performance wise especially if you are working with a WSDL that is not expected to change frequently.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment, I will try it out. Out of interest do you know whether my program can be modified to set the ws-timeouts before the WSDL is requested? I would have thought this should be possible?

Comment: @Alex:I think that the WSDL is accessed at `Service.create(new URL(wsdlURL), serviceName);`. Since the setting of timeout is on the dispatcher, I can not see how it is possible to set it before. The system properties though should help you since jax-ws uses HttpUrlConnection under the covers for the communication with the server. IMHO though you should keep the wsdl cached to avoid the remote fetch and also avoid these kind of issues.

Comment: @Alex: Check this http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/200902.mbox/%3Ce507996c0902190158n5906bf01qecee0ae439c25bb@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: hi yes Im caching the WSDL's, as in keeping a map of Dispatch objects against each service. Im assuming this the correct way to do this?

Comment: @Alex:Did you you try the system properties? Did it work? Caching the wsdl means that it will not be fetched from server (no POST request) but the cached copy will be used instead

Comment: @user384706 I set both the sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout and sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout system properties (before the WSDL is accessed). Unfortunately it made no difference. :-( When you mention about caching the WSDL during runtime, is there an option in the JAX-WS API that achieves this ? Note: I have no knowledge of any WSDL when the application starts.

Comment: @Alex:You tried `System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "1000");` and
`System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout", "1000");` and did not work? How about `java -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout="1000" etc`.  
Concerning the wsdl caching try:    
`URL wsdlUrl = MyClass.class.getResource("/class/path/towsdl/WSDLFile.wsdl");Service service= Service.create(wsdlUrl,etc);`

Comment: @user384706 I tried setting both System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "10000"); and System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout", "10000"); and the timeout was about 90seconds. With WSDL caching, note I have no WSDL built into the application (ie on startup all I know about is a WSDL location on the Internet), so can Service.create(wsdlURL,etc); somehow cache that WSDL it obtains into a defined path ?

Comment: @Alex:No, you are supposed to have the wsdl stored locally.You have the wsdl file locally and you provide the file-path to the wsdl on service creation as in the example in the previous note. You should be able to do that. The wsdl is accessible for you to have local

Comment: @user384706 the requirement for this application is that it "dynamically invokes" Web Services from loading a config XML file that has all the Web Services WSDL URLs. The set of Web Services can change during runtime by re-loading a new config file in. So the app can never have the WSDL's stored locally before runtime.

Comment: If you can't cache the WSDL it seems that it's impossible to configure timeout for WSDL fetch.If you check http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/no-timeout-set-when-fetching-wsdl-0 http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/timeout-service-client-creation-0 they have the same issue but I don't see if it is fixed.You can ask there if has been fixed.For now do the following:call the `Service.create` from a different thread. If after your timeout period `Service.create` has not returned interrupt the thread.It is dirty and not sure if it will work but try.

Answer (score 2):

We just ran into this same issue, and tried all of the settings mentioned above - likewise, to no avail.

Our solution was to download the WSDL to a temporary file first, using URL.openConnection() (setting the timeouts on the connection with: URLConnection.setConnectionTimeout(), and URLConnection.setReadTimeout()). We then generate a url for this file with: File.toURI().toURL(), which we pass to the service constructor that takes a URL.

This approach lets you dynamically fetch the current WSDL, while explicitly controlling the timeout. We then set the timeout for subsequent calls to the service as you show in the original post.

Comment: What about the XSD?  The downloaded WSDL points to the XSD. I'm just wondering: Will JAX-WS RI (aka Metro) ever try to download that one as well?

Comment: I'm not certain (it's been years since I looked at this) - but perhaps the specified (longer) timeout is being used at that point. What I do know is that this resolved the issue.  :)

Comment: I guess I meant: Who really knows what meta-data JAX-WS RI requires at runtime?. Will it only try to get hold of the .wsdl file or will it also try to get hold of the .xsd file?  The .wsdl file has a link to the .xsd file. I've seen JAX-WS RI requesting .xsd file from the server (although it doesn't seem to happen in the 'normal' case). In other words: One day your solution may break because JAX-WS RI will suddenly **also** try to get hold of the .xsd file ... and then what?  (part of this is speculative)